# Explode multiple slices of pie by grouping types in same group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I really like the "explode" option on matplotlib pie charts. I was hoping to be able to "explode in groups". I'm plotting lots of little slices that fall into 3 or 4 categories. I'd like to explode all the little slices together, as groups.

```
# Data is in this format:
axis1    
Unix    A     3
        B     1
        D     1
Window  C    30
Apple   A     1
        D    12
Linux   A    10
        C    20 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
labels=["{0} {1}".format(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in data.index]
wedges, texts, percs = ax.pie(data, labels= labels  ,  autopct=  '%1.1f%%',shadow=True, radius=3) #lambda p:f'{p:.2f}%' if p > 10 else '')
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

I've tried:

```
groups = ["{0}".format(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in data.index]

for i in groups:
    ang = np.deg2rad((wedges[i[-1]].theta2 + wedges[i[0]].theta2)/2)
```

But I'm getting the following error:
`"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"`.

The desired result would look something like this:

[image: Desired result for grouping in Pie chart]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explode multiple slices of pie together in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549016/explode-multiple-slices-of-pie-together-in-matplotlib)